# how do you regex

Tags: regex

I have a variable that is like this:

```
server.cpu_usage
```

I need to regex out everything after the dot, not including dot.

I tried this but it is including dot:

```
(\..*$)
```

Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a *positive lookbehind*:

```
(?<=\.).*$
```

This pattern says "anything *preceded* by a dot until end".
See http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html.

Alternatively, simply a capture group:

```
\.(.*)$
```

Then use `match[1]` (specifics depend on your language of choice).

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is correct. You need to exclude the dot from the capturing group, and also you need to print the group index 1 in-order to get the desired output.

```
\.(.*)$
```